# ffmpeg cut, fade and concat causes the video to get stuck

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, video, media, concatenation

I'm trying to add "fade out" effect to a long video. One method I explored is cutting video at the end before few seconds, adding the fade out effect to the second split and concat both the splits.

I came up with below commands.

```
:: Cut the video into 2
ffmpeg -i myvideo.mp4 -c copy -map 0 -segment_time 00:00:40 -f segment -reset_timestamps 1 -y "split%%01d.mp4"

:: Add the fade out effect
ffmpeg -i split1.mp4 -vf "fade=t=out:st=5:color=red" split1-m.mp4 -y

:: Merge them without re-encoding
ffmpeg -safe 0 -f concat -i videolist.txt -c copy splitcombine.mp4 -y
```

When I play the combined video in Chrome, the video is stuck at the join. In VLC, there is a blank stutter.

*(in Chrome video player video is stuck at the join. If I resume the video, it ends)*

[image]

*(in VLC)*

[image: resume]

If I remove the "fade out" effect and simply combine, there is no issue. (left no fade out effect. right with fade effect)

[image: Split without fade out effect]
[image: Split with fade out effect]

I'm not sure what is the issue here.

Any ideas would be greatly helpful! Any other ideas to achieve the similar result is also welcomed!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it out myself. I used `ffprobe` and compared the difference between the faded video and the second split video.

The faded video had a different pix_fmt than the other split. I then normalized the pixel format by adding `-pix_fmt yuv420p` since the other split had the same.

With this, the combined video was working without any glitch.